# Add left and right padding to UIButton

Tags: swift, uikit

I would like to add some left and right padding to buttons, which I see they have a `titleEdgeInsets` property. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class QuickPromptButton: UIButton {

    var userFacingValue: String?
    var answerValue: String?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.primaryColor.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.cornerRadius = 15
        setTitleColor(.primaryColor, for: .normal)
        titleEdgeInsets = .init(top: 0, left: -10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
        contentVerticalAlignment = .center
        contentHorizontalAlignment = .center

    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

However, this is what they look like now:

[image]

The problem is that the text goes out of the borders. Any idea why?

This is what I get by using 10 on both left and right:

[image]

Comment: Cool, using 10/10 on both sides works but the text gets truncated...

Comment: Thanks as always @matt - do you know what is the name of that method? Not sure if it's `drawRect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    let originalSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
    let size = CGSize(width: originalSize.width + 20, height: originalSize.height)
    return size
}
```

Overriding `intrinsicContentSize` and adding the total padding on top of the current width ended up working for me, although not sure if this is the right approach.